# Delete One of two folders with the Same Name by command line

Tags: command-line, directory

I want to delete one of two folders which is having exactly same name but containing different files in it.
How can i delete specific folder from these two in terminal ?

Comment: What? You can't have two subdirectories in a directory with exactly the same name...

Comment: The two directories (folders) must have either a different name or different path (location). You would use the proper name or proper path with the rm command `rm -rfi /path/to/directory` , careful with the rm command, if you use the wrong location you will loose data.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I have this situation in a directory. It happens due to copying a directory(of same name) by scp command from remote.

Comment: Are you sure there is no whitespace at the end of one of the names and the case of all characters is the same?

Comment: @DurgeshSuthar Can you post the output of `ls` command when you are in the parrent directory of those two directories? I'm very curious...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu : ls is giving me two sub-directories with exactly same name.

Comment: @DurgeshSuthar Can you post the output on http://paste.ubuntu.com/? Copy exactly as it is from terminal.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu : I am not sure if there was whitespace at the end of name. Now i renamed one of them and deleted as i posted in Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by a different way.
Like someone have two folders of same name as *sub* in a directory *dir*
First I renamed one of directory ( I don't know which). Then checked the directory got renamed by seeing contents of it.

> mv dir/sub dir/sub1

And then deleted the directory which is not required ( live *sub1* is not required)

> rm -r dir/sub1